# After reload collectionview,it always move to the first cell if also select the last cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, swift4

[I have attached this image. You can see the problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aAOv.gif) I have implemented the horizontal collection view where cells contains label. When we select the not visible items of the cell (after the first load 4 to 5 items are visible) and reload the cell it always moves to first visible cells.how should I handle the this problem?

```
func collectionView(
        _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
        cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:
    "profile_CollectionViewCell_city", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as!
            profile_CollectionViewCell
    cell.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    if ((self.data_array[indexPath.row] as! NSMutableDictionary)["title"] != nil) {
        cell.city_name.text = ((self.data_array[indexPath.row] as! NSMutableDictionary)["title"] as? String)?.uppercased()
    }
    if (indexPath.row == selectedIndex) {
        cell.city_name.textColor = UIColor(red: (0.0 / 255.0), green: (120.0 / 255.0), blue: (56.0 / 255.0), alpha: 1)
        cell.city_name.font = UIFont(name: "Poppins-Bold", size: 14)
        cell.lower_view.isHidden = false
    } else {
        cell.city_name.textColor = UIColor(red: (156.0 / 255.0), green: (156.0 / 255.0), blue: (156.0 / 255.0), alpha: 1)
        cell.city_name.font = UIFont(name: "Poppins-Light", size: 14)
        cell.lower_view.isHidden = true
    }

    return cell
}

func collectionView(
        _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
        numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data_array.count
}

func collectionView(
        _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layoutCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        sizeForItemAtIndexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let size = ((self.data_array[indexPath.row] as!
            NSMutableDictionary)["title"] as? String)?.size(withAttributes:
    nil) ?? CGSize.zero
    return size
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedIndex = indexPath.row
    self.city_table.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Please reply soon - this is very motivating. You didn't even post any code

Comment: please display your code

Comment: @JigarDarji check this code. I have posted my code.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha check this code. I have posted my code.

Comment: in this code which line you reload collectionview?

Comment: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt 
 indexPath: IndexPath)
{self.city_table.reloadData()}

Comment: self.city_table.reloadData() i think you reload tableview not collectionview

Comment: actually "city_table" is a name of collectionView.Its a collectionview

Comment: try this code city_table.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .top)

Comment: Not Working....

Comment: Can you please try this,        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedIndex = indexPath.row
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }

Comment: @Sarmistha i tested your code and working perfect.

Comment: @PPL  If I don't reload the cell its not showing the effect of selected cell bold.

Comment: @JigarDarji I don't know what happen actually.Its same as it is.I have to scroll manually to see which one is selected when I click cell from after 3rd index of cell.

Comment: if you have demo than send me i will check whats your problem bcs i dont understand

Comment: @JigarDarji Check this link. https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aAOv.gif.

Comment: i cant see anything in screeshot bcs data does not display.record video and send

Comment: @JigarDarji check this video link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ts3yqmc789najp6/demoCollection.mov?dl=0

Comment: okey i got it please give me some time i will check

Comment: check this demo https://wetransfer.com/downloads/6ea726acdbe512e89390db5bf2ac0b6e20180608115439/13049d

Comment: you got solution? @Sarmistha

Comment: No in my codes may be any other issues. What you have sent me its already implemented as same in my code.I have to check it thoroughly.